# Cloudinary Image Path NOT Saved in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, express, cloudinary

I am building an express app which has a form with an option to upload a single image. I have implemented the image upload using cloudinary sdk for node.js nad returned success. I can see the image url in my console and tested it to be sure. Like:

```
Product Cloud Image URL:        http://res.cloudinary.com/joey17/image/upload/v1520120085/bte0bhzl6ljcuqmr3vgn.jpg
img url value:    http://res.cloudinary.com/joey17/image/upload/v1520120085/bte0bhzl6ljcuqmr3vgn.jpg
```

The problem occurs when I try to save this path in mongodb. I have this snippet to save the inputs and image from the form like below:

```
let imgUrl = "";

    cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files.image.path, (resultImage) => {
        console.log('Product Cloud Image URL:\t' + resultImage.url);
        imgUrl = resultImage.url;
        console.log('img url value:\t' + imgUrl);
    });

    Products.findOne({slug: slug})
        .select('_id title slug image desc price category')
        .exec()
        .then(product => {
            if (product) {
                req.flash('danger', 'Product Title Already Exists');
                res.render('admin/add_product', {
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    price: price,
                    desc: desc,
                    category: cat,
                    image: imgUrl
                });
            } else { // start reading from here... sorry had to include the other parts above
                console.log('Unique Product Slug');

                let price2 = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);

                let product = new Products({
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    price: price2,
                    desc: desc,
                    category: cat,
                    image: imgUrl
                });

                product.save()
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log('Product Created:\t' + data);

                        req.flash('success', 'New Product Created');
                        res.redirect('/admin/products');
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.error('Error Saving Product:\t' + e);
                    });


            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
}

});
```

In mongo compass, I have checked but the value for the image is an empty string like: `' '`. Here's a snippet of the newly created product:

```
 _id: ObjectId("5a9b307937766901104addf8")
 title: "Blue Shirt"
 slug: "blue-shirt"
 price: 123
 desc: "a blue ocean"
 category: "clothes"
 image: ""
 __v: 0
```

I dont understand why the cloudinary path is not saved. Please someone should help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: My bad, I should save the product inside the cloudinary callback. First person to comment with this answer will be accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you put your `Products.findOne()` to the `cloudinary.uploader.upload()`'s callback. Because the upload function is a synchronize call. So, you have to let your saving function to wait it.

```js
let imgUrl = "";

    cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files.image.path, (resultImage) => {
        console.log('Product Cloud Image URL:\t' + resultImage.url);
        imgUrl = resultImage.url;
        console.log('img url value:\t' + imgUrl);
        
        Products.findOne({slug: slug})
        .select('_id title slug image desc price category')
        .exec()
        .then(product => {
            if (product) {
                req.flash('danger', 'Product Title Already Exists');
                res.render('admin/add_product', {
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    price: price,
                    desc: desc,
                    category: cat,
                    image: imgUrl
                });
            } else { // start reading from here... sorry had to include the other parts above
                console.log('Unique Product Slug');

                let price2 = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);

                let product = new Products({
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    price: price2,
                    desc: desc,
                    category: cat,
                    image: imgUrl
                });

                product.save()
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log('Product Created:\t' + data);

                        req.flash('success', 'New Product Created');
                        res.redirect('/admin/products');
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.error('Error Saving Product:\t' + e);
                    });


            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
}

});
    });
```

### For upload to a specific folder:

First, go to this link https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload
And find "**Upload presets**" section to create a preset which can let you choose which folder you want to use. Secondly, your upload code should seem like this (I use Axios)

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('upload_preset', 'Your preset name');
fd.append('file', file);
return axios.post(API_CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL, fd, { headers: { 'X-Requested-
With': 'XMLHttpRequest' } }).then(result => result.data);
```

#### If you are using Cloudinary's uploader, according to Cloudinary website:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.unsigned_upload("sample.jpg", "unsigned_1", 
{ cloud_name: "demo" }, 
function(error, result) {console.log(result) });
```

unsigned_1 is your preset name.
The full documentation is here: [Documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#unsigned_upload)
I hope it can help. :)

Comment: YEs, I figured that out. SO doesn't have live reload. Thanks buddy

Comment: Is it possible to save the image into a folder online?

Comment: Yes, you can go to Cloudinary settings section to setup a Upload presets which can let you assign a folder. When you code uploads the image, you can choose to use different presets to control which folder you want to upload to.

Comment: I have checked the docs and console but don't understand it. Can you share an example?

Comment: It is hard to use this comment to show code. So, I will post it in my original answer.

Comment: I'm using express default router not axios. How do I integrate that to my app and what package should I install to use form data? Kindly edit my code snippet to show this part clearly. Thanks

Comment: I add some code that Cloudinary documentation showed as well as the link of the full documentation. I hope it can help.

Comment: Yes. The v2 of the api does that. I have also edited my code with that but the result.url returns undefined. How do I get the path it is saved in in the cloud?

Comment: Did you mean when you use cloudinary.v2.uploader.unsigned_upload, the result return you a undefined? Please be aware two places: 1. You have already set up the preset upload in the settings area. 2. The first parameter of  callback function for this version is error, the second one is result.

Comment: It worked as soon as I added the error part of the callback. Thanks so much bruh!!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.

Comment: I want to upload more images under a particular image, is it possible? I'm building an ecommerce app and I need gallery images. I find cloudinary far easier than others. Whats the best approach with cloudinary? Thanks